# VBA-Macro para filtrar data e colar num novo livro se este não existir, e colar na última célula preenchida

Tags: excel-vba

Boa Noite, 
Sou Novo no VBA e estou a tentar desenvolver uma macro que me faça o seguinte:
tenho Vários dados em 5 colunas e o que pretendo fazer é um filtro pela coluna [E] e que adicione novo livro em csv com o nome do filtro, mas se o livro já existir então vai colar os dados de acordo a coluna [A].
ex:macro faz filtro pela coluna E, copia linha 1, 2 para um novo livro com o nome 100, se esse livro já existe, então vai copiar os dados e colar na ultima célula preenchida se não existir as datas 15/08/2019 ou 16/08/2019, se as datas existirem então substituir os dados.
O que tenho até agora é a seguinte macro que encontrei na internet.
se me pudessem ajudar agradecia imenso, obrigado.

```
Sub DistributeRowsToNewWBS()
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsCrit As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim rngCrit As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set wsData = Worksheets("Folha1")            ' name of worksheet with the data
    Set wsCrit = Worksheets.Add

    LastRow = wsData.Range("e" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' column H has the criteria
    wsData.Range("e1:e" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wsCrit.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

    Set rngCrit = wsCrit.Range("A2")
    While rngCrit.Value <> ""
        Set wsNew = Worksheets.Add
        ' change E to reflect columns to copy
        wsData.Range("A1:E" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=rngCrit.Offset(-1).Resize(2), CopyToRange:=wsNew.Range("A1"), Unique:=True
        wsNew.Name = rngCrit
        wsNew.Copy
        Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
        ' saves new workbook in path of existing workbook
        wbNew.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & rngCrit
        wbNew.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wsNew.Delete
        rngCrit.EntireRow.Delete
        Set rngCrit = wsCrit.Range("A2")
    Wend

    wsCrit.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]